# How to get sleep or turn off time settings

Tags: android, kotlin, android-settings, android-powermanager

I am investigating an issue, where android device is being automatically turned off without any reason.

The device was left yesterday running, with 57% battery. Today in the morning, the device was turned off. After starting the device, the battery shown 43%.

The following call returns 60s as screen off timeout - which is ok.

```
Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT)
```

How can I get sleep timeout? I can see the following as hiden.

```
public static final String SLEEP_TIMEOUT = "sleep_timeout";
```

It is not visible to my code, and invoking the following returns 0 and throws exception without the default value ...

```
Settings.System.getInt(contentResolver, "sleep_timeout", 0)
```

And is there some `turnoff_timeout` settings to be checked?